# How to unpublished a node from a view?

Tags: views, nodes

I have a list of all nodes (in my specific case Product Display, generated in Commerce kickstart) using a view. Is there a quick way I can have an unpublish/publish option right there in the view results list? I'd like to avoid the following everytime I need to perform this operation.

1. browsing to **Node/Edit**
2. selecting the **publish options** tab
3. (un)ticking **Published**
4. hitting Save

Does anyone know of a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to achieve this. VBO lets you select various nodes in a list and then perform an action to all of them. VBO is highly customizable and extendible. VBO can be combined with other modules like mighty [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and others. Bulk publishing and  unpublishing would (of course) also be possible.

ps: actually this could also be achived through the 'regular' content handling (/admin/content). Just set the content type filter to your content type and you can already bulk publish/unpublish. But I suppose you tried this already and would prefer to have the same nodes as you have in the view?

Comment: The problem with that option is the only bulk operation appears to be Delete. Can it be adjusted for other operations?

Comment: Well – at least the screenshot at the module's page suggests that a lot more should be possible: https://www.drupal.org/files/images/views_bulk_operations.png

Comment: ahha. thanks I found the options to perform this operation now. it of course unearths more problems for me, but at least this one is resolved.